# Password strength validation java

Tags: java

I need to write a program to check the strength of a password based on following conditions and output the type of password as "Too short", "Weak", "Medium" or "Strong"

Conditions: 
1) Password should be 8 characters long 
2) it should contain at least one uppercase and one lowercase letter 3) it should contain one or more of these special characters: ~, !, @, #, $, %, ^, &, * 
4) it should contain one or more digits in it The output is defined as: if first condition fails, then output = "Too short" if only two conditions including first one

is met, then output = "Weak" if only three conditions including first one is met, then output = "Medium" if all four conditions are met, then output = "Strong"
Below is the code I have written:

```
class PasswordStrengthValidation
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the password");
        String inputPassword = scan.next();
        int uppercase = 0;
        int lowercase = 0;
        int specialcharacters = 0;
        int digits = 0;
        char[] Password = inputPassword.toCharArray();
        for (int index = 0; index < inputPassword.length(); index++)
        {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(Password[index]))
            {
                uppercase = 1;
            }
            if (Character.isLowerCase(Password[index]))
            {
                lowercase = 1;
            }
            if (Character.isDigit(Password[index]))
            {
                digits = 1;
            }
        }
        if (inputPassword.contains("~") || inputPassword.contains("!") || inputPassword.contains("@")
            || inputPassword.contains("#") || inputPassword.contains("$") || inputPassword.contains("%")
            || inputPassword.contains("^") || inputPassword.contains("&") || inputPassword.contains("*")) ;
        {
            specialcharacters = 1;
        }
        if (inputPassword.length() < 8)

            System.out.println("Too Short");

        if (inputPassword.length() >= 8 && (((uppercase == 1) && (lowercase == 1)) || (digits == 1) || (specialcharacters == 1)))

            System.out.println("Weak");

        if ((inputPassword.length() >= 8 && (((uppercase == 1) && (lowercase == 1)) || (digits == 1) && (specialcharacters == 1)))
            &&
            (inputPassword.length() >= 8 && (((uppercase == 1) && (lowercase == 1)) && (digits == 1) || (specialcharacters == 1))))

            System.out.println("Medium");

        if (inputPassword.length() >= 8 && (uppercase == 1) && (lowercase == 1) && (digits == 1) && (specialcharacters == 1))

            System.out.println("Strong");

    }
}
```

However when I try to implement the below code by giving an input of "Password" which falls under the "Weak" category I get the output as Weak followed by Medium. Can someone please help me as to where am I going wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please learn correct indentation if you're going to post your code here. It makes it easier to read. Your IDE can basically do it automatically so there really is no excuse. I've fixed it for you this time.

Comment: You are missing the ´else if´ after the first if with println.

Comment: Combining `(((uppercase == 1) && (lowercase == 1)) || (digits == 1) && (specialcharacters == 1))` and `(((uppercase == 1) && (lowercase == 1)) && (digits == 1) || (specialcharacters == 1)))` looks rather wrong. Also mind that `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`. Thus then you write `(upper && lower) && digits || special`, then you only need "special" to fulfil that expression https://ideone.com/wTV2hG

Comment: Just a side note: [Password rules are bullsh*t](https://blog.codinghorror.com/password-rules-are-bullshit/). So your code should output always `"Weak"`

Comment: You should make a simple test from the code that checks conditions and prints the password strength (everything after the loop, basically). Once you do that, you will be able to see that some of your conditions overlap, and it's indeed possible to enter a password that would be considered both `Weak` and `Medium` at the same time.

Comment: I second what @Tom said, plus that making the use of `else if` rather than all `if`'s could be helpful

Answer (score 6):

I suggest use a regex

```
if (inputPassword.matches("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})")){
    System.out.println("Strong");
} else if (inputPassword.matches("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.{8,})")){
    System.out.println("Medium");
} else if (inputPassword.matches("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.{8,})")){
    System.out.println("Weak");
} else if (inputPassword.matches("^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.{8,})")){
    System.out.println("Weak");
} // etc
```

you can adjust conditions removing or change conditions in the expression

- **(?=.*[a-z])**  The string must contain at least 1 lowercase alphabetical
  character
- **(?=.*[A-Z])**  The string must contain at least 1 uppercase
  alphabetical character
- **(?=.*[0-9])**  The string must contain at least 1
        numeric character
- **(?=.[!@#\$%\^&])** The string must contain at least    one special
  character, but we are escaping reserved RegEx characters    to avoid
  conflict
- **(?=.{8,})**    The string must be eight characters or    longer

Comment: thanks for the regEx. I just had to replace the last part of it to make it work. It shouldn't be a lookahead but rather something to match. So instead of `(?=.{8,})` I had to use simply `.{8,}`.